# onvif protocol GetSnapshotUri and bash

Tags: bash, ip-camera

i've a camera that support onvif protocol
i need to retrive a snapshot from it , in a bash script , but for this i need to have the url were i can retrive it!!!
i've tried the most common url for taking the snapshot without success

the onvif protocol, have a call "GetSnapshotUri" that respond with the valid uri that i need, but i don't know how to send this call to the camera

i've read somethings and i've see that need to send a soap request to do that, but im' not so skilled to do it!

Answer (score 0):

solved, 
with the app ONVIFER for android, i make a debug log, and sent it via email to my address, inside the log there're the dialog beetween the smartphone and the camera, and YES, there's the answer to the "GetSnapshotUri" command
tried, an YES it's works